# Angular material shows nothing

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm begining with Angular material. On a sample project I've installed @angular/cdk and @angular/material and add references on app.module.

Then at a template I put a simple object :

```
<md-checkbox>Testing </md-checkbox>
```

But when I run the app the checkbox shows only "Testing" and not the checkbox. No error on console.

The app.module :

```
   import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ServiceHTTP } from './service-http.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule} from 'angularfire2/auth';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ConsultaComponent } from './consulta/consulta.component';
import { BsNavbarComponent } from './bs-navbar/bs-navbar.component';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MdButtonModule , MdCardModule , MdMenuModule , MdToolbarModule , MdIconModule , MdCheckbox} from '@angular/material';


import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ConsultaComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    BsNavbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MdButtonModule , MdCardModule , MdMenuModule , MdToolbarModule , MdIconModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
      {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
      {path: 'consulta', component : ConsultaComponent}      
    ])

  ],
  providers: [ServiceHTTP],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you show your app.module.ts imports?

Comment: Shure @Z. Bagley , I put the code at the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're only importing the checkbox, and not the entire module (which uses a lot of other items).

```
import { ..., MdCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material';
```

should solve the problem!

(don't forget to add it to your @NgModule imports as well)

Comment: Yep, shure  ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to import  **`MdCheckboxModule`** as well

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MdButtonModule , MdCardModule , MdMenuModule , MdToolbarModule , MdCheckboxModule,MdIconModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
      {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
      {path: 'consulta', component : ConsultaComponent}      
    ])

  ]
```